# move subdirectory in laravel storage folder

Tags: laravel

I can move 3 images in `public/page/hello-word` directory under normal conditions. However, I cannot migrate because of the `public/page/hello-word/images/` directory and the images in the directory. I am getting an access error.
How can I perform a Laravel Storage migration?

What I want to do is, if the `slug` from the request is changed, I move the images with the new `slug` with the code I gave below, but I get an access error because it is a subdirectory.

```
message: "rename(C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\storage\\app\\public/page/hello-word,C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\storage\\app\\public/page/hello-word-aa-a): Access Denied (code: 5)"
```

```
$data = Page::find($id);
if ($data->slug !== $request->slug) {
            $controller = Page::where('slug', '=', $request->slug)->first();
            if (!$controller) {
                Storage::move('public/page/' . $data->slug, 'public/page/' . $request->slug);

            }
        }
```

```
[0] => public/page/hello-word/images/2022-01-yatak-degistirme-1659267107.jpg
    [1] => public/page/hello-word/images/2022-01-yatak-degistirme-medium-1659267107.jpg
    [2] => public/page/hello-word/images/2022-01-yatak-degistirme-small-1659267107.jpg
    [3] => public/page/hello-word/images/287571104-1779438322407849-3191366792335714739-n-1659267108.jpg
    [4] => public/page/hello-word/images/287571104-1779438322407849-3191366792335714739-n-medium-1659267108.jpg
    [5] => public/page/hello-word/images/287571104-1779438322407849-3191366792335714739-n-small-1659267108.jpg
    [6] => public/page/hello-word/images/40-indirim-banner-1659267106.jpg
    [7] => public/page/hello-word/images/40-indirim-banner-medium-1659267106.jpg
    [8] => public/page/hello-word/images/40-indirim-banner-small-1659267106.jpg
    [9] => public/page/hello-word/images/ayin-urunu-banner-2022-1-web-1659267109.jpg
    [10] => public/page/hello-word/images/ayin-urunu-banner-2022-1-web-medium-1659267109.jpg
    [11] => public/page/hello-word/images/ayin-urunu-banner-2022-1-web-small-1659267109.jpg
    [12] => public/page/hello-word/resim-yok-1659267086.jpg
    [13] => public/page/hello-word/resim-yok-medium-1659267086.jpg
    [14] => public/page/hello-word/resim-yok-small-1659267086.jpg
```

Comment: Its somewhat bizarre that you store the images in a folder named the same as the slug

Comment: I didn't ask the question to be weird :) I opened the topic because I wanted to do it or didn't see such a question

Comment: My point is, you have tied the folder name to something that is likely to change. Now you are having to jump through hoops to allow the user to change the slug.  Better to use the post ID or a random token for the folder name which you can then save in the database